# Struggling with C Strings and printf %s

Tags: c, string, field

So I struggle since a long time with a (I guess simple) problem with strings in C.

I want to create a list of `char` pointers and allocate by `malloc()` each of them some memory to fill with a single random character. At last I want to sort them and build up a new string with `strcat()`.

So in this code only the first part is shown with some testfunctions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Error, too few arguments!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // initialize random generator
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    const int a = atoi(argv[1]);

    char *array[a];

    //--------------- generate random characters ----------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        int r = rand() % 30 + 1;
        printf("%d ", r);

        array[i] = (char*)malloc(a + 1 * sizeof(char));

        sprintf(array[i], "%ls", &r);
        *(array[i] + 1) = '\0';
    }

    putchar('\n');
    printf("%d %d %d \n", *array[0], *array[1], *array[2]);

    char *array_2 = (char*) malloc(a * sizeof(char));

    strcat(array_2, *array);
    strcat(array_2, *(array + 1));
    strcat(array_2, *(array + 2));

    printf("Address array_2[0] : %p , value: %d \n", array_2, *array_2);
    printf("Address array_2[1] : %p , value: %d \n", &array_2[1], array_2[1]);
    printf("Address array_2[1] : %p , value: %d \n", &array_2[2], array_2[2]);

    // produces a lot a garbage and crap
    printf("array_2 with string : %s :\n", array_2);

    // rest of the code omitted because it is irrelevant to the issue
    return 0;
}
```

So, what I don't understand: Printing the characters separately works fine. If I want to print the whole thing as a string, I only get a noisy string of characters. How can I realize the idea?

Honestly, I don't get the problem - if I create a character array like `char array[4] = {'a','b','c', '\0'}` I can print the whole thing with "%s"... But in my program it is almost the same but doesn't work.

I would be glad if somebody could give me a hint!

Comment: `a + 1 * sizeof(char)` = `a + 1`

Comment: Should the strings contain the random number `r`? If so, the `sprintf` looks fishy, it should be `sprintf(array[i], "%d", r)` and you don't need to place the null terminator the explicitly. (Your code for that will keep only the first digit of the number.) Also, in order to hold a number from 0 to 30 as string, you will need at most 3 bytes. This size does not change with the amount of strings, `a`. Likewise, if `a == 2`, for example, there won't be an `array[2]`, which you access unconditionally.

Comment: Some issues in your source: 1) No need to cast the result of `malloc()`. 2) Should `malloc(a + 1 * sizeof(char))` be `malloc((a + 1) * sizeof(char))`? 3) `sizeof (char)` is defined to be 1, but makes code clearer. 4) Why do you allocate increasing sizes to `array[i]`? 5) Why do you use the format "%ls" (with lower case 'L') ad give it the address of the local variable `r`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- The dimensions of the arrays are wrong. The `a` strings in `array` will hold a random number from 0 to 30, so each requires at most 3 bytes (two digits and the null character), but you allocate `a` bytes. These numbers are unrelated. `array_2` must hold a concatenation of all `array` strings, so it will be at most `2*a` bytes long and it needs one extra byte for the null character at the end.
- Your `sprintf` is wrong: `sprintf(array[i], "%ls", &r)` tries to interpret the address of the integer `r` as the address of a wide char array. (This really looks as if you had fiddled with the format and argument until the compiler was silent.) To print the number `r` to the string, use `sprintf(array[i], "%d", r)`.
- `sprintf` will already null-terminate your string, so there is no need to do that explicitly.
- As Ruslan has already pointed out, your `array_2` points to uninitialized memory. The function `strcat` requires a null-terminated string. You can make `array_2` a valid empty string by setting the first char to the null char `'\0'`.

In order to fix your code, I suggest the following:

- Make `array` an array of strings of size 3. Don't allocate them on the heap, but make them automatic variables on the stack, which is easier to manage.
- When you create the number strings, keep track of how long they are. The `*printf` functions have a useful return value, namely the number of characters that were printed or written to a string / file. Use that length to allocate memory for `array_2`.
- Initialize `array_2` as valid, empty string, then `strcat` all `array` strings to `array_2`.
- Do interesting stuff with `array_2`, then `free`the allocated memory.

Here's the code for that:

```
int a = 8;
char array[a][3];
int len = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    int r = rand() % 30 + 1;

    printf("%d\n", r);
    len += sprintf(array[i], "%d", r);
}

char *array_2 = malloc(len + 1);

*array_2 = '\0';
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    strcat(array_2, array[i]);
}

printf("\"%s\"\n", array_2);
free(array_2);
```

Comment: Since the code already uses one variable length array, you can use `char array2[len + 1];`, too, for simplicity.

Comment: Hey, I'm really glad that you took the time to clear out 'my problem' with this programm! Really helpful, so I can recognize that I have to work out several points in C language, but your tips make it much easier for me, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

> `char *array_2 = (char*) malloc(a * sizeof(char));`
>
> `strcat(array_2, *array);`

You've allocated `array_2`, not initialized it, and then you're appending `*array` to whatever garbage `array_2` had. That garbage likely contains lots of control characters, printable characters and whatnot before a null char occurs, so you get all these characters on your console (possibly with occasional beeps).

Comment: thank you for you hint! It helps me to understand the whole system better!